# Two-way authentication using ssl in dotnet

Tags: vb.net, authentication, ssl-certificate, two-way, ssl-security

I have a project where I need to send a datafile through a web request.  We need to setup Two-way authentication also known as mutual authentication.  We are not sure if we need a special cert or not but we know that it needs to be level 3.

I am having trouble finding sample code for this case. I don't know where to add our cert information.  With this code a `Underlying connection is closed` error is thrown when we try to read the response stream and `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is never called.  Here is what I have:

```vb
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf MyCertValidationCb)
            httpReq = CType(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            For Each cert As String In certs
                X509cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(cert)
                X509cert2 = New X509Certificate2(X509cert)
                httpReq.ClientCertificates.Add(X509cert2)
            Next
            httpReq.Method = "POST"        ' Post method
            httpReq.ContentType = "text/xml"               ' content type

            ' Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
            writer = New StreamWriter(httpReq.GetRequestStream())
            ' Write the XML text into the stream
            reader = New StreamReader(filename.Name)
            ret = reader.ReadToEnd()
            reader.Close()
            ' Send the data to the webserver
            writer.WriteLine(ret)
            writer.Close()
            ' Wait for response
            Dim httpRsp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(httpReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            sr = New StreamReader(httpRsp.GetResponseStream)
            responseText = sr.ReadToEnd

            If httpReq IsNot Nothing Then
                httpReq.GetRequestStream().Close()
            End If
            If httpRsp IsNot Nothing Then
                httpRsp.GetResponseStream().Close()
            End If
```

Any tips or links to blogs with sample code would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a particular requirement that prevents using WS-Security on SOAP? Between .NET and IIS, i.e., WCF, this would handle SSL transport and repudiation using a shared cert. Switching up to TLS and/or message encryption is a matter of setting flags. No need for a Class 3 then, just a Class 1 PKCS12, with private key, no need for a trusted chain root, would work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a 'special' certificate. Your client needs its own certificate and use it in the connection to tell the server its identity. That is called a Client Certificate. The server should handle this properly.

The following MSDN article talks about how to set your ClientCertificate:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2